# enable/disable domain redirection

Tags: networking, iptables, dns, dnsmasq

My router can be joined by clients.

**enable** // I'd like to redirect all traffic to an IP (`13.37.42.1`), I mean any IP and any domain.

**disable** //
Then I d like to be able to **disable** it. Then clients can browse the web
I can do that for IP but not with IPTables.

**How can I do that** ?

Here is my **router** config:

---

**dhcpd.conf**

```
option domain-name-servers 13.37.42.1;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;    
authoritative;
log-facility local7;

    subnet 13.37.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        #option domain-name "wifi.localhost";
        option routers 13.37.42.1;  
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option broadcast-address 13.37.0.0;    
        option domain-name-servers 13.37.42.1;
        range dynamic-bootp 13.37.42.15 13.37.42.100;   
    }
```

**dnsmasq.conf**

```
bogus-priv
filterwin2k
no-resolv
no-dhcp-interface=wlan0
interface=wlan0
**address=/#/13.37.42.1**
domain=bbox
```

Finally, I turned on `ip_forward`:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

I guess my system cannot find DNS resolver anywhere (?)

Comment: What are IP addresses assigned to your router and client?  And please give some examples of IP addresses that worked with your browser as you expected.

Comment: `broadcast-address` should be `13.37.42.255`.  You should check your clients resolve every domain name to 13.37.42.1 using DNS utility like `host`, `dig` or `nslookup`.  And, can you open `http://13.37.42.1/` with your browser and see content intended for clients?

Comment: @yaegashi thanks. Yes I can open `http://13.37.42.1` with a client browser, and see content indeed. + `address=/#/13.37.42.1` resolve every domain name to 13.37.42.1, this is the problem. If I comment `address=/#/13.37.42.1`, i can get no DNS resolving. Note : I do want my clients access Internet, if they enter `www.someting.com`, then they do see `www.someting.com'

Comment: @yaegashi where shall I add `broadcast-address` please ?

Comment: Modify that in `dhcpd.conf`: it should be `option broadcast-address 13.37.42.255;`.  If you want clients to normally resolve domain names using dnsmasq, just remove `no-resolv`, or add `server=<upstream DNS address>` in `dnsmasq.conf`.